How to get temperature and humidity data from a Sensiron SHT3X
The more I read, the more confused I become...
I have a SHT30 Temperature And Humidity Sensor. I bought it from Adafroot some time ago, but never found a real use for it. Now that Raspberry Pi has evolved to 'bookworm', the Linux kernel is at ver 6.6+, and sysfs has been reported as "cast aside", I decided to wire this sensor up and see what could be done with it.
The SHT30 sensor is not manufactured by AdaFroot; they only buy the sensor, mount it on a "breakout board", and provide some software & "how-to" advice on using the sensor. Much of their advice is geared toward the Arduino platform, or to CircuitPython. Frankly, I found most of AdaFrœt's documentation for using the SHT30 with a Raspberry Pi incomprehensible!
I need a straightforward explanation on how to get the temperature and humidity data from a Sensiron SHT3X sensor - one that does not involve CircuitPython or other AdaFrõt foolishness.

Don'y you realise that life would be much simpler (for Adafruit) if everyone adopted CircuitPython rather than standard Python or MicroPython.

This video tutorial may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwC0U_UbVzE

@Milliways: Ach! You're correct of course... what was I thinking?

NOTE sysfs has not been deprecated (only GPIO support). I use for PWM. I don't know if I²C works.

@Milliways:   But... they are all GPIO  :)  And yes, i2c works; in fact all i2c connections are placed under sysfs.

1. The first step is to connect the sensor to the RPi:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
2. The second step is to declare an overlay:
Run raspi-config; in the Interfaces section, ensure that the I2C interface is enabled. Note that I use i2c0 for this example, but any available i2c channel may be used. Open file /boot/firmware/config.txt (for RPi OS 'bookworm') in your editor, and add the following lines. You will need to reboot after making these changes:
dtoverlay=i2c0 

dtoverlay=i2c-sensor,i2c0,sht3x

3. Consult the documentation:
A better source for documentation on the SHT3X is the Sensiron website. You will find application & driver software here, but we will not require that for this example.
Instead, we will use documentation for the Linux kernel; specifically: the driver documentation for the SHT3x. This document contains the sysfs interface documentation, and is the key for using the sensor. It does not explain exactly where in /sys these interface files are found, but a bit of digging around, with help from grep revealed its location to be as follows on my RPi 3A+:
$ grep -s sht3x /sys/class/hwmon/*/*   
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/name:sht3x
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/uevent:OF_NAME=sht3x
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/uevent:OF_FULLNAME=/soc/i2c@7e205000/sht3x@44
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/uevent:OF_COMPATIBLE_0=sensirion,sht3x

$ cd /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2
$ ls -l 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 device -> ../../../0-0044
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 heater_enable
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_alarm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_max_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_min
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_min_hyst
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 name
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 of_node -> ../../../../../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/soc/i2c@7e205000/sht3x@44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 repeatability
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../class/hwmon
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_alarm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_max_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_min
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_min_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:52 uevent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 update_interval

Which we see matches the kernel documentation for the SHT3X.
Note also that the directory name reflects my use of i2c0 - instead of the default i2c1.  i2c1 was already being used for a Real Time Clock on the RPi 3A+ and was not available.
The availability of the driver documentation and sysfs interface description provide for a very straightforward method to control the sensor, and take readings from it. This may perhaps be done most simply using a shell script to read/write the sysfs files:
#!/usr/bin/bash

# verify the assumed sysfs folder exists, and contains the correct 'name' file
# read current temp & humidity from files
# assumed sysfs folders as follows:
#   /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2
#   /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2 (a symlink to /sys/devices/...)
# use 'grep -s sht3x /sys/class/hwmon/*/*' to locate the correct folder in sysfs

dev_fldr="/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2"
#
# check that $dev_fldr exists, that the file 'name' exists in it, and that the file contains 'sht3X'
if [ -d "$dev_fldr" ] && [ -f "$dev_fldr/name" ] && [ $(< "$dev_fldr/name") = "sht3x" ]; then
    dev_nm="sht3x"
else
    echo "ERROR fm $0: The named sysfs folder: $dev_fldr - appears to be incorrect."
    echo "run the command: 'grep -s sht3x /sys/class/hwmon/*/*' to relocate dev_fldr"
    echo "and update this script with the new value/location."
    exit 1
fi

# Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 1.8) + 32
# read sht3x sensor's temperature & humidity data
denominator=1000
temp_c=$(< "$dev_fldr/temp1_input")
t_c=$(echo "scale=1; $temp_c / $denominator" | bc)
t_f=$(echo "scale=1; ($t_c * 1.8) + 32" | bc)
# echo -e "$t_c deg C\t$t_f deg F"

humid_r=$(< "$dev_fldr/humidity1_input")
h_r=$(echo "scale=1; $humid_r / $denominator" | bc)
# echo "$h_r per cent"

printf "Temperature: %4.1f deg C, %5.1f deg F\tHumidity: %4.1f %% relative humidity\n" $t_c $t_f $h_r

This simple script reads temperature and humidity measured by the sensor; each run will yield one measurement each for temperature & humidity. I wanted true floating point calculations in this script, so I installed and used bc. If you'd like to see some alternatives for using floating point numbers in bash I'd suggest this excellent article.
This script implements a one-time measurement. The update_interval file defaults to 0 - for "single-shot mode"; this may be changed by writing an appropriate value to the file.
EDIT:
The problem with this answer is that sysfs is re-written by the kernel at each boot, and there's no guarantee that the kernel will always use the same device folder name!! Since we depend upon an invariant sysfs folder name in the above script - we're screwed!!.
There are two (maybe more??) methods to deal with this inconvenience:

Incorporate a grep or find function in the script to re-locate the correct device folder (kinda' hack-y IMHO), or ...

Use udev to create a symlink to the correct folder.


I chose udev. I've written that solution up here as a recipe as it would have made this answer even longer!
The udev solution is to create a new file at /etc/udev/rules.d/80-local.rules with the following single line in it:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hwmon", ATTR{name}=="sht3x", KERNELS=="0-0044", SUBSYSTEMS=="i2c", SYMLINK+="i2c_sht3x"

There was also a corresponding change to the bash script as follows:
# FROM: 
dev_fldr="/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2" 
# TO: 
dev_fldr="/dev/hwmon_sht3x" 

The explanations got rather lengthy, and I chose not to incorporate them here. If you're interested, see the recipe for the sht3x script, and the recipe for the udev stuff at my GitHub site.

Great write-up. Only note would be if the OP did something strange set the base shell as something other than bash. (so long as bash is installed your fine) Otherwise the bashism using redirection inside the command substitution would need to be a read or UUOc (Unnecessary Use Of cat) heaven forbid. Otherwise a C implementation using the gpio_v2 ioctl() interface would also work nicely -- more lines of course.

@DavidC.Rankin: I used bash because I didn't want to use Python, couldn't find a decent C library, and wanted to learn more about sysfs. I'd love to see an answer that used C - esp ioctl (or udev) - hint, hint.

Hmm, I don't have an I2C for SHT3X, but do have an example for an ADS1115 ADC and a gpio_v2 implementation at Raspberry Pi Peripheral Access Wtihout root. You can check the examples/ads1115 and tst/gpio_v2_button_value sources and Makefiles. (there is also SPI and hardware and software PWM examples as well). The new kernel gpio_v2 uABI is excellent (once you make friends with it) kernel-doc for uABI. I think I lost some hair in the process.

If looking for something simpler by any chance, you can try DHT11. https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2022/04/interface-dht11-sensor-with-raspberry-pi-4.html

@liaifat85: In the link, they state, "The microcontroller DHT11 has a power consumption of 3 to 5 volts." ...  That's a little too simple for me   :)
